# LoaderManager reference not found with API Level 17

Tags: java, android, android-loadermanager

I am writing an android sample app and trying to create sample of listview using sample code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). And it can't resolve LoaderManager. Any idea what could be wrong?

I am using eclipse toolkit with latest android sdk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `LoaderManager` you need to use in this example is only available from the API 17 :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

I guess you are using an API inferior to 17 so your project cannot find it.

In case you really need to use this function on older API versions, you can still have a try using the "support" version available in the support library:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html

Using this package you can import this `LoaderManager` class using:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
```

Instead of:

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
```

Comment: Only API i am referencing is 17. Project is targeted for 17, also min version is also 17. So i guess this should be ok.

Comment: Well it was just the error correction issue with eclipse. It wasn't suggesting to import namespace when usually it does for everything else. Adding import manually fixed the issue.

Comment: @Manu - maybe you could add an answer with this in it as adding the import manually fixed it for me also. It would be interesting to see if anybody can explain why this is necessary and whether this is in fact the correct fix for this issue (although what Yoann says is of equally valid for anyone with an mismatched API level).